# How to route in Angular 2 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am following the [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/); currently at the [Routing section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html). I am using the 2.0.0-RC4 bundle.

I have successfully refactored the `AppComponent` into a shell for the `HeroesComponent`. I have also added routes, loaded the necessary files, and done the necessary bootstrapping.

**index.js** — had to add the router beneath platform-browser because that's what I read in the `ng-router` source; `provideRouter` returns false otherwise

```
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
    app.ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

**app.routes.js**

```
(function (app) {
  const routes = [
    { path: 'heroes', component: app.HeroesComponent }
  ];

  app.ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    ng.router.provideRouter(routes)
  ];
})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

**app.component.js**

```
(function (app) {
  app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'ig-app',
    directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [app.HeroService],
    template:`
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Heroes</a>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
    }).Class({
      constructor: function() {
        this.title = 'Tour of Heroes';
      }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

This loads my app with a Heroes link. But there is an error on the console

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any
>   routes: ''

And then I append `/heroes` to the URL, the Heroes component does not load, and I get the following error in my console

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined

Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong?

#### EDIT

When I specify the route for `''` in my routes file like so...

**app.routes.js**

```
(function (app) {
  const routes = [
    { path: 'heroes', component: app.HeroesComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ];

  app.ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    ng.router.provideRouter(routes)
  ];
})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

I get the second error I listed above on both pages. If I try setting it to the `app.AppComponent` I get errors which hint I should have a `redirectTo`

Comment: What do you get if you log ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES to the console in the first line of the self calling method in app.component.js?

Comment: @Yoda an array of functions: RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkWithRef, RouterLinkActive

Comment: @Yasky I have the same problem, you solve this problem?

Comment: @fantianyi I haven't visited this for a while now. If you find a solution, do well to post it up.

Comment: @Yasky I solved the problem, please flowing answer.

Answer (score 1):

I completing the Angular 2 Example, Tour Of Heroes, the Routing section, use ES5.

I upload code to [github](https://github.com/fantianyi/Angular-2-Example---Tour-Of-Heroes---6-Routing---ES5).

I am using the 2.0.0-RC5 bundle. I can not solve the proble using the 2.0.0-RC4 bundle!

flowing the part code:

**app.routes.js**

```
(function(app) {
  app.routing = ng.router.RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: app.DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'heroes', component: app.HeroesComponent},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: app.HeroDetailComponent}
  ]);
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not know what to display in the `<router-outlet>` **before** you navigate to the *heroes* path.
You need to define the route for the empty ('') path and create HomeComponent, EmptyComponent or whatever suits your needs. Or you can define redirect for the empty path.

Comment: I tried this and the second error in my question showed up on the first page

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is a path for your empty route ' '...

you can do this by adding a route as below in your app.routes.js file

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/your_path' ,pathMatch: 'full' }
```

that's it bro :)

Comment: When I do that, I get the second error on the first page.

Comment: can u show me the component of your redirectTo path ?

Comment: actually i was asking you to show me your component ,in this case your component is app.HeroesComponent  ... can u show me ur app.HeroesComponent file

Comment: It's long. The only directive is the `app.HeroDetailComponet`, and the constructor is an injector type which injects `app.HeroService`. I can give more details if you ask specifically

Comment: can u create a plunkr for this ?? otherwise its not possible to detect why are u facing such a problem..

Answer (score 0):

As others say, you need the route for ''.
Your second error is probably in your heroescomponent code.